# grunt error while running task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

While running a task via grunt, I'm getting this error I couldn't figure out what can it be.
Can you help me by giving me ideas what can possibly be wrong?
[image: grunt error]

I already had similar errors to this that I couldn't find the root cause, so I copied the node_modules folder from another project that was running ok, but now I really want to understand what can be possibly going wrong... and the error message doesn't help me.. It seems too generic.

Comment: It looks like you need to [update `grunt-notify`](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify/issues/118). So you know how I came to that conclusion: the error seems to be stemming from the `grunt-notify` package so I Googled "grunt-notify ENOENT" and this came up.

Comment: thanks mike! I'll try that and I'll keep you updated! I had similar problems while installing npm and it was all related to old versions of packages, and it may be that too

Comment: @MikeC that's it! I updated grunt-notify package and it worked well! I changed my machine for a new one and since I had to reinstall node/npm I think the old versions of packages stopped working with this new version.. so that's it! thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed MikeC advice and updated the grunt-notify package to version 0.4.5 and now it is working like a charm!